# Script to rename the first 6 files in a folder

Tags: php, batch-file

I am looking for a script that can rename the first 6 files in a folder. I have a folder of files and I would like those renamed to 1-6 for another script I made. Is there a way to do this?

The only caveat is the files are named using a timestamp so they are somewhat random so I need a way to rename *.txt but only the first 6. Anyone got any ideas?

For example, a batch script like this, but one that only renames some, not all

```
    ren *.html *.txt
```

or a php script like this that only renames some, not all.

```
<?php
rename('*.txt', 'newname.txt');
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by the fisrt six? wich six ?

Comment: plenty of ways, show a promising effort..

Comment: How are you ordering these files? Alphabetically?

Comment: how about this, any six files. Though preferably just the first six .txt files in the source folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specified how to sort them, or how exactly you wish to rename them. Sorry, my mana run out so propably my answer would not solve your problem. But let's try.

Open directory, iterate over files, and increase counter on every loop, when counter reach 6, break the loop:

```
<?php

$folderpath = '/path/to/folder';

if($handle = opendir($folderpath)) {

    $cnt = 0;

    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle)) {

        if(is_dir($folderpath . '/' . $file)) // skip if directory
            continue;

        if(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) != 'txt') // skip if filename doesn't end with .txt
            continue;

        // create new name by replacing trailing .txt to .html:

        $newname = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $newname .= '.html';

        if(rename($folderpath . '/' . $file, $folderpath . '/' . $newname))
            $cnt++; // increase counter only if rename success

        if($cnt >= 6)
            break;
    }

    closedir($handle);
?>
```

Comment: genius. I forgot about loop counters. Let me try this out.

Comment: Few fixes added. But i think that You know the idea ;)

Comment: dreamweaver is having issue with this line while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle)) { also you are missing a } me thinks

Comment: you were missing a closing bracket on the script and missing a closing ")" on this line while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle)) { an  but it works so I am going to mess with it.

Comment: @Lucas: Your answer was not helpful. [It caused an additional question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327271/script-to-rename-the-files-with-sequential-numbers). So instead of one question (the one here) it created another one.

Comment: @dreamweaver unfortunately, stackoverflow's textarea doesn't support features like vim's showmatches and it was something about 0:30AM my local time. Dunno why dreamweaver has personality problems with my code. But good to know, all future projects will held notice about not to edit them in DW ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a one-liner in bash

```
ls *.txt | head -6 | xargs -I{} mv "{}" /destination
```

That should do the first six that are listed alphabetically

Comment: Is there a way to run this from WAMP? I have php running on a windows machine.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of and certainly not very easily.  It's Linux/Unix

Comment: @SuperMar1o: Install git bash and you can just use this on windows.